# OS X application in full screen mode on two monitor setup

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nsapplication

Basically I would like to run OS X application in full screen mode on two monitors. There is no specific layout I would like to accomplish, I would just like to zoom in application to use whole two screens. Only application that I saw behaves that way is parallels.

How do I accomplish that ?

UPDATE:

This application will run only on my personal setup where i have two screens with the same resolution. OSx application contains two tableview's. One table view have one column and second tableview have numerous columns. In fullscreen mode i would like to see as much of those columns from tableview2. Preferable would be that tableview2 stretches to use both screens.

Comment: You mean like spreading your application main window on two monitors?

Comment: Yes. But also hiding dock and toolbar on main monitor screen.

Comment: The only way I see is to have tow fullscreen windows providing appropriate views to achieve the targeted effect (you have to deal with the fact that the screens may not be the same size & resolution. Imagine a retina macbook pro on an apple display)

Comment: @Jean - I've never, ever worked on a setup where both screens had the same size ;-)

Comment: @Gossamer: Sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414099/cocoa-open-a-fullscreen-window-on-the-second-screen-maintaining-the-app-visible/15473114#15473114)?

Comment: @Jay Me neither, but there is no harm in reminding this fact ;) I know a couple of developers who had to solve this very issue. They lost track of the the screen sizes during the process... and result was… well, it was not what they expected. However, the solution used is the one I describe above (They also had to mind the order of the displays)

Answer (score -1):

There are several different approaches that you could use:

1. Create two full screen windows in which you will put two scrollviews
   containing two tableviews displaying your data. 
   Then, you will
   need to scroll the tableviews to the appropriate position, in order
   to display your content. You will also have to synchronize scrolling between the views.
2. Create one window that you enlarge, so that it spans across the monitor. This will be far easier than solution (1) since your displays are the same size. You have one large tableview. You have to take care of the dock and the toolbar.
3. Other solutions, requiring more voodoo. Not worthy of detailing.

**Pro / Cons**

**Solution 1:** the OS takes care of the dock and the toolbar for you. it is easy to deal with display of different size / resolution. But the setup (programmatically) requires some amount of effort.

**Solution 2:** Easy to setup. But you have to take care of the dock and the toolbar, and won't really work if the displays are of different size/resolution.