# Display NSWindow on secondary screen

Tags: cocoa

I would like to display an `NSWindow` created in a storyboard full screen on a secondary monitor. The below code results in the window being displayed on the primary screen/main screen. The Y origin is ok but the X origin is 0 where it should be -1680. The code below worked before Yosemite.

```
NSScreen *screen = [[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:2];
NSRect mainDisplayRect = [screen frame];
[PresenterWindow setFrame: mainDisplayRect display:YES animate:YES];
[PresenterWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
[PresenterWindow setLevel: CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
```

I had also tried the following with the same result:

```
[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, [screen frame].size.width, [screen frame].size.height) 
                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                              backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                defer:NO
                               screen:screen];
```

Please advise how I can fix this.

I've tried solutions from some other questions:

- [Cocoa Open a fullscreen window on the second screen maintaining the app visible on the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414099/cocoa-open-a-fullscreen-window-on-the-second-screen-maintaining-the-app-visible) - did not work - same result.
- [Display os x window full screen on secondary monitor using Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401240/display-os-x-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-cocoa) - nope - neither with `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` method of NSView.

I have some new observations:

If i activate the "Launch At Startup" in the storyboard for my `NSWindow` the window is viewed fullscreen on my secondary monitor. If i then do a `orderOut` and run the above code the window is viewed in correct size but on my primary/main screen. The window is not activated to "Release When Close". So when I deactivate "Launch At Startup" the window is again viewed in the primary/main screen with the size of the secondary screen.

Comment: Try setting the window level before ordering it in. If that doesn't work, try overriding `-constrainFrameRect:toScreen:` to just return the passed-in rect.

Comment: Thank you Ken, but i did not help. I found out that it did work if I activated "Visible At Launch" for my NSWindow in the storyboard. If I then programmable ordered the window out, then next time is run the initial script it was wrong again.

Answer (score 3):

After some days I got it to work:

The NSWindow in the storyboard was marked with "Launch At Startup"

In the applcationDidFinishLaunching i wrote the following:

```
[PresenterWindow setLevel: NSNormalWindowLevel];
[PresenterWindow orderOut:self];
```

To open full screen I used this:

```
NSScreen *screen = [[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
NSRect mainDisplayRect = [screen frame];
[PresenterWindow setFrame: mainDisplayRect display:YES animate:YES];
[PresenterWindow setLevel: CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
[PresenterWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:screen];
```

To close full screen and to be able to open full screen again correctly:

```
[PresenterWindow setLevel: NSNormalWindowLevel];
[PresenterWindow orderOut:(sender)];
```

Comment: Any chance this has been updated to swift 4+?  I'm working on essentially the same thing, but I do not know obj-c in order to update/convert this to swift 4+.